# When does lambda + api gateway actually send a response to the client?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Currently I've setup a lambda function that is triggered from an api gateway end point. The goal was to keep response times low by forming the response and triggering the callback first, and then continuing on to interact with sns to pass of work to other lambda functions. However, I've been noticing some odd behavior when running blazemeter against the endpoint. Mainly the response times seem to continually increase, furthermore there are 502 and 504 response codes returned but no 500 response codes (which if i understand correctly, indicate invocation throttling since 429 response are mapped to 500 in api gateway). If i remove the asynchronous actions I see reasonable response times and and no errors. Why is this the observed behavior, does the order in which items get queued on the nodejs event loop not effect when the response is actually triggered or does lambda just wait for the event queue to empty out before sending the response? If the latter, then would errors in the async interaction be the cause of the 502 & 504 responses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> does the order in which items get queued on the nodejs event loop not
>   effect when the response is actually triggered or does lambda just
>   wait for the event queue to empty out before sending the response?

By default a NodeJS 4.2 Lambda Function will wait for the NodeJS event loop to be empty before exiting and triggering API Gateway to send a response. When you call the `callback` function it simply notifies the Lambda container to exit once the event loop is clear. API Gateway doesn't return a response until the Lambda function exits. You could set an option to trigger the Lambda function to exit as soon as you call the `callback` function, but then the other stuff you have running in the background would be killed.

> If the latter, then would errors in the async interaction be the
>   cause of the 502 & 504 responses?

If by "the async interaction" you mean the calls to SNS that you are making, then yes if those failed and you didn't handle the error properly it could cause the entire invocation to return an error. If you are getting 502 errors you need to check your [Lambda function's logs in CloudWatch Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-logs.html) to see what the errors are. You can also [enable CloudWatch Logs for API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudwatch-logs/) which might provide some helpful information in this case.

Comment: Have you found a way to trigger ApiGateway while simultaneously keep lambda's tear-down code running?